# I get "too many redirects error" in higher android api versions while using jsoup with android studio

Tags: android-studio, jsoup

I'm learning jsoup with android studio. I tried the following code in intellij and it worked fine. Also it works fine in the api vesrion 19 but not for the higher api versions.

```
    private TextView textView;
    private static final String TAG = "Main2Activity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView2);


        getWebsite();


    }


    private void getWebsite() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    String url = "https://isa.ir/content/3895/";

                    Connection.Response response;

                    response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                            .followRedirects(true)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36 OPR/64.0.3417.150")
                            .execute();

                    Log.d(TAG, "run: " + response.statusCode());
                    Log.d(TAG, "run: " + response.headers().toString());


                        Document doc = response.parse();
                        final Elements text = doc.select(".yw_cnt div:nth-child(2)");
                        Log.d(TAG, "run: " + text.text());
                        for (Element link : text) {
                            builder.append(link.text());
                        }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    builder.append("Error : ").append(e.getMessage()).append("\n");
                }

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(builder.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

I get the too many redirects error.

Also the link https://isa.ir/content/3895/ turns into https://isa.ir/content/3895/%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87-%D8%B8%D9%81%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%87-%D8%B3%D8%A7%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%B6%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C-%D8%A7%DB%8C%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AA%D8%AD%D9%88%DB%8C%D9%84-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%B4%D8%AF in the browser.

In the Logcat while testing, I get the redirected URL correctly in API 19, but in higher APIs the Persian characters turn into question marks like this https://isa.ir/content/3886/????????.
I think I tested everything related to encoding but still the problem persists.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to redirect programmatically.

Set `followRedirects(false)` and execute it.

1. If response status code is between 301-307, read the redirect location.
2. Then load the new url.

Do this steps until the response status code is OK.

Checkout [this](https://mkyong.com/java/jsoup-check-redirect-url/) example

Comment: It never gives the OK status code. It just repeats the same URL multiple times.